# TI SensorTag firmware Update through OAD(over-the air ) in android

Tags: bluetooth, sensors, download-manager

Help me to upload firmware through android app in nexus 7 ,as I have build my sensor tag project through IAR embedded workbench,but I didnt find any app for OAD firmware update in android, when I am trying to update firmware through TI ble device manager android app, its telling "OAD service is not available" while it has OAD service uuid0xFFC0.

Comment: Could you try to write this question in sentences? At the moment it's really hard to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have TI sensor tag device with some different-2 sensors.Ijust wanted to update the firmware of that device using android app named "Bluetooth device manager" but I am unable to update because I am getting One issue ""OAD service is not available". @DanHulme

Comment: Since that's a pretty niche desire, you're most likely to get an answer by asking the developers of that app.

Answer (score 1):

It's not available because you have an old version of the TI firmware in your SensorTag. Some months ago they added the "Connection control service" to the SensorTag firmware to enable OAD with Android. If your firmware is not recent, it has the OAD Service but not the Connection Control Service, so you'll have to use iOS to to OAD.